# Best way to use production database data for unit testing database data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing

I am wondering if anyone can tell me the best way to populate test data in a test database from a real live database? (For use in Unit testing)

For example. I have a Sql Server Database that contains 1000's of records. I want to use that data for test cases in my C# testing project. It would be very time consuming to create the data manually.

I figured the best way to do this would be to generate c# code that will recreate the data in a test database for when I run the tests. But how would one do that? or would people typically just export a big SQL Statement in this sort of scenario and execute that against a test database?

The other obvious way to do it is to use a copy of the production database. My issue with that is, the data structure is still changing...which causes problems...

I am using SqlServer LocalDB, C#.

Thank you kindly for any advice

Comment: SQL Server allows you to export a create database with the data it has. It also allows you to create backups from which you can create copies. People normally use one of those methods

Comment: Restore the db from a copy of productio. Use a sql server database project in visual studio. You can write post/pre deployment scripts and then publish the database. This will allow you to keep making changes to the schema. Having said that, unit tests should not depend on db. Those are intégration tests.

Comment: Using a copy of live data for testing purposes (although easier) is not good practice. Depending on where you live, like Europe, doing so can result in hefty fines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation

Comment: I think the best way is to create a staging database that is copy of production database.
Also the purpose of staging is you can also make of it as bug and fix testing before deploying the fix to production.

Comment: How would you know that the prod data copy covers exercises all your test cases? Not saying it would be better to create your own small set to test data so you are sure all cases are covered and automated tests run faster.

Comment: Hi Dan, I don't. Some of my tests are performance based. I.e. I am trying to find the fastest way to do things. That's one reason. But the truth of the matter is: You raise an important point :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool from microsoft (free) that I used successfully to copy small / medium amount of data, you can check it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

If the data has not too much columns you can also work with HeidiSQL and its CSV export import feature. Indeed this is free as well.